# Map static classes with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to map static classes with AutoMapper?

Scenario is like this. There is a static class called `UserIdentity` and it contains properties. I want to map `UserIdentity` class values to my none static class called `UserDTO`.

When I tried

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserIdentity, UserDTO>();
```

There is an error saying,

```
static type cannot be used as type arguments
```

Now can anyone explain me about this scenario and is it achievable or not. And is there a way to map static classes without using Automapper. Otherwise I have to do them manually.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to use a dummy class to perform a no-op mapping.  Then you could use a custom type converter, or mapping function or simply do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Dummy, Dest>()
  .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
     { 
         dest.Name = UserIdentity.Name;
         dest.Id = UserIdentity.Id;
         //.... etc..
     });
```

Comment: So, to paraphrase, no, you can't. And, in this case, why include AutoMapper at all? If you're going to end up mapping the properties by hand, anyway.

Comment: @AndrewTheken - well, if you're already using AutoMapper for other things, it makes sense to keep all your mapping using similar patterns for the sake of consistency, even if it means doing some work arounds to make some types work.

Comment: With due respect, I think that it's a matter of style, and I guess I just don't agree that adding code that does nothing, even if it "matches style" contributes to readability when raw C# is going to be less "magical."

Comment: @AndrewTheken - Does nothing?  It clearly does something... Not sure what your point is.  If your alternative is to fill your controllers with messy mapping logic instead of abstracting it into a single place, then.. well, I guess we have different ideas of what "style" is.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said all of this in a way that didn't escalate it, I don't want to argue with you about it. I feel like you're putting words in my mouth about "filling your controllers," and as I made no such implication - you can just as easily write this mapping in a static method share it throughout the application. My point was that "using" automapper adds unnecessary indirection for the sake of consistency, and this is in fact a case that is, by definition, not the same as the other uses of AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant use automapper on static classes

Additionally there are a very limited set of situations in which you can refer to static class types, which will also make other approaches difficult

Static classes prevent inappropriate use, so in almost all situations, you can't use them in situations where you'd normally want an instance of the type... and that includes type arguments.

The only way i can see to achieve your desired results is to create a field by field mapping function your self

All though you can force automapper to use a dummy class, you are still mapping field by field anyway, my vote is to reduce complexity and just use something like the following

```
  public static SomeDTO CreateDTO()
  {
     return new SomeDTO
        {
            dest.Name = UserIdentity.Name;
            dest.Id = UserIdentity.Id;
            ect..
        }
  }
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample code to get an idea for create field by field mapping function?